# Git. "npm link" files are not ignored in the (node_modules is in gitignre)

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, npm-link

A other local npm repository was link with the npm link command. Sample: `npm link "@test\xyz"`. Despite the node_modules folder beeing already in the .gitignore the links was marked as changed.

Adding another File, Link etc to the node_modules folder was not detected as change.

Sorucetree and npm commit don't detect changes.

Anybody else encounted that?

Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are also a couple of reports of it on Microsoft Connect.  You should vote for the issue there.  I reported it in October.

[.gitignore not being honored when using SymLinks](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/128473/gitignore-not-being-honored-when-using-symlinks.html)

Comment: thanks, it is similar to the one I worte: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/145995/git-npm-link-files-are-not-ignored-in-the-node-mod.html
and you already commented on :)